# Possible Ways to Parse JSON in Android

Tags: android, json

I'm curious as to the best way to parse a JSON object within Android.  I'm getting the string from a php script and then parsing and displaying the information within the Android App.  I'm wondering what the best format would be for the PHP script's string it is sending.

Information the Script is sending is probably going to be different every time so it's not necessarily going to be the same every time.  It will send a Name, Address, then an identifier for how many other objects, then the other objects with a title, id, and text.  Is it possible to parse a String that is in this format:

```
{"name":"Ted", "address":"111 ..."} {"num":"2"} {"title":"Test","id":"1","text":"Hello"} {"title":"Test2","id":"0","text":"Hey"}
```

Comment: is it a valid json. check it here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't know there was a validation site for JSON.  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

You can use for it [built-in apache json module](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html), [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

Comment: Can you parse the string I provided using the built in JSON Module though?  I have been capable of parsing a simple object but never had to deal with multiple objects previously.

Comment: first of all, your json string isn't valid